# mysql login as root works for one ubuntu user, but not another

Tags: mysql, debian

I have two linux users (not mysql users), root and deploy. If I login as root and do

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

it works fine.  If I login as deploy and do

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

I get

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Do I have to set a per-linux-user permission?

Comment: Check each user's `~/.my.cnf` file. One may be defining a default `host` to connect to. Remember that MySQL credentials are a combination of user, password, and client host, and "localhost" is not the same thing as "127.0.0.1". The former uses the socket file, the latter uses TCP/IP, and they each have different entries in the MySQL credential table.

Comment: thanks for your reply, no such file for both accounts, deploy has .  ..  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  .bundle  .gem  .gnupg  .mkshrc  .profile  .rvm  .ssh  .viminfo  .zlogin  .zshrc and root has .  ..  .bash_history  .bashrc  .gnupg  .mysql_history  .nano  .profile  .viminfo

Comment: It could also be in the `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html for env variables used by MySQL programs.

Comment: You can log in from root, the way that works and run `SHOW GRANTS` to get it to tell you if it thinks you're root@localhost or root@127.0.0.1 or root@something-else.

Comment: @BillKarwin, do you think this sounds like it could be [`auth_socket`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html)?

Comment: @BillKarwin SHOW GRANTS reveals it's localhost.  It turns out I installed with apt-get install mysql-server but what was installed was MariaDB.  I'm speculating that MariaDB has some user based authentication, unlike the old mysql, but this is speculation.  If I run mysql -uroot -hlocalhost on root, it works fine, same command on deploy, same error.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, that's a possibility. This would allow authentication only by a Linux user with the same name as the MySQL user, when connecting to localhost (i.e. via UNIX socket). Check with `SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE '%socket%';`

Comment: SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE '%socket%';
+-------------+---------------+
| PLUGIN_NAME | PLUGIN_STATUS |
+-------------+---------------+
| unix_socket | ACTIVE        |
+-------------+---------------+

Comment: thanks for your help guys, it is definitely the maria auth socket plugin. if you want to post an answer i'll mark it as the answer.